# Google Maps Polyline and Marker together

Tags: google-maps

I have this code for polyline which is working perfect. How do i add marker for each of location point?

```
var userCoor = [
<?php
for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($lat); $i++)
echo "new google.maps.LatLng({$lat[$i]}, {$long[$i]}),";
?>
];

var userCoordinate = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: userCoor,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWeight: 2
});

userCoordinate.setMap(map);
```

I tried

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < userCoor.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(userCoor[i][1], userCoor[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(userCoor[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
}
```

Marker seems missing? Any idea how? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how userCoor goes from new.google.maps.LatLng to an array holding `content` and two floats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested with some bogus data here and there doesn't seem to be a problem. The difference is I'm using `userCoorPath` for the polyline and `userCoor` to set the markers. I'm repeating the information, but they are being used differently. One is an array of LatLngs, the other an array of string and two floats.

http://jsfiddle.net/nSf9N/

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the marker `icon` property.

Also, you are overwriting the marker variable.  Perhaps that has something to do with it.  try movinf your marker variable definition inside the loop.

Comment: Actually marker appeared on first point itself and not on all coordinate