# Showing a Tripple in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have following problem, which I am currently trying to implement:

I have tripples of information/location which I wanna display in Google Maps (API 3)
Showing one selected location in a sidewindow and showing the corresponding dot on the map is easy but I have:

- 3+ locations to show simultaniously +
- I wanna combine/link them maybe with a polyline to show, that they belong together.

Is this even possible in google maps, someone has information about such a try?

Comment: If you are asking what I think, it is certainly possible.  What have you tried? Do you have an example of what you are trying to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple markers simultaneously on a canvas, but remember you should push a new marker to an array in order to play with it later.

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/nSf9N/. It's belong to this post [Google Maps Polyline and Marker together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237589/google-maps-polyline-and-marker-together)
I guess it is exactly you want